# Как в условии цикла while проверить 2 переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Как сравнить 2 переменные в цикле while? Цель в том, чтобы цикл повторялся пока значение одной переменной не станет равно значению другой переменной, при этом одна из переменных определенна за ранее, а другая меняется на единицу при каждом повторении цикла, тем самым происходит перебор значение и на каждый повтор цикла выполняется тело цикла. Тело цикла будет выполнять функцию подсчета процентов, и подсчета увлечения этой суммы с годами с учетом процентов.

При вводе суммы скажем "10000" и срока хранения в "12", в консоле выводит 1100.0, хотя требуется чтобы на каждое число из 12, выполнялось тело цикла, вычисляя тем самым итоговую сумму, то есть он за 1 год подсчитывает а потом цикл заканчивает свою работу, хотя не должен, по моему разумению

```
num1 = int(input('Введите сумму: '))

#Ввод срока хранения суммы
num2 = int(input('Введите срок: '))

#Вычисление увеличения суммы с 10% годовых
num3 = 0
while num3 < num2:
    #Вычисление 10% от введеного пользователем числа
    num4 = num1/100*10
    
    #Вычисление увиличения суммы с учетом процетов
    num4 = num4 + num1
    
    #Увеление значения на 1, чтобы перебрать каждый год и подсчитать прибыль
    num3 = num3 + 1

print('Сумма увеличится до: ' + str(num4))
```

Comment: В этом коде правильно проверяется.

Comment: Совет: давайте переменным понятные имена. Завтра же будете смотреть в свой код и думать что это за num1 и num2 и что за ними скрывается.

Comment: я пользуюсь этим, всм даю понятные имена перменным, это кусок когда в котором проблемы, специально для вопроса собрал, чтобы показать в чем вопрос

Comment: Ну вот если бы называли понятно, то не получилось бы, что одна переменная одновременно и 10% от суммы и общая сумма.

Comment: Все верно, первое выражение вычисляет процент и записывает его в переменную num3, а затем в эту же переменную перезаписывается процент сложенный с суммой, тем самым показывая на сколько увеличится введенная пользователем сумма, не вижу проблемы тут

Comment: А в том, что это происходит в цикле тоже не видите? Что происходит во второй итерации? А в третьей?

Comment: По задумке, первое выражение в цикле это вычисления 10 процентов от введенной суммы, второе выражение это увлечение введенной суммы на подсчитанное ранее кол во процентов, третье выражение увеличение на единицу переменной, что указанна в условие цикла, тем самым приближая её к равенству с переменной отвечающей за введенное кол во срока хранения суммы, второго повторения цикла не проходит судя по тому что выводится в консоль, из чего я делаю вывод что условия выполнения цикла не верно оформлены, то есть не True, отсюда и вопрос

Comment: Был бы благодарен если точнее укажите на то что я сделал не правильно, это бы очень помогло

Comment: Условия оформлены верно. Но вы КАЖДЫЙ РАЗ перезаписываете значение num4  в строчке num4 = num1/100*10, теряя предыдущее значение. И если бы использовали одну переменную под каждую задачу, то этой проблемы бы не возникло. Не говоря уже о том, что 10% достоточно вычислить только один раз, т.к. Num1 не изменяется.

Comment: Спасибо большое, ответы ниже помогли решить проблему, но пока вы не указали на ошибку я не мог взять в толк, почему при повторении цикла не увеличивается сумма, теперь просмотрел все заново и понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while num2 != num3
```

но лучше сделать это с помощью цикла `for`

```
money = int(input('Введите сумму: '))

year = int(input('Введите срок: '))

for _ in range(year):
     money += money / 100 * 10

print('Сумма увеличится до: ' + str(money))
```

Comment: Ещё лучше использовать известную формулу вообще без использования циклов.

Comment: Цикл for помог, но возникли дополнительные вопросы.                                                                       1. что значит  _  в цикле for?                                                                                                                   2. money += money / 100 * 10 это тоже самое что и money = money + money / 100 * 10

Comment: 3. про какую известную формулу идет речь и как её использовать без цикла 4. почему лучше использовать цикл for нежели цикл while?

Comment: @Danis задал вопросы без упоминания, сорян, только осваиваюсь на сайте

Comment: @Анатолий Михеенко 1.`_` нужен чтобы не создавать лишних переменных 2.Да 3.Я не знаю

Answer (score 3):

способ 1:

```
for cycle in range(num2):
    # действия
```

способ 2:

```
cycle = 0
while cycle < num2:
    # действия
    cycle += 1
```

следующий способ небезопасный, поскольку могут быть такие `num2`, что из цикла и не выйти (есть `num2 = 0` или действительному числу)

```
cycle = 0
while cycle != num2:
    # действия
    cycle += 1
```

способ 3:

```
cycle = num2
while cycle > 0:
    # действия
    cycle -= 1
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что в 1 способе должна быть еще строка `cycle = 0` в начале, перед циклом `for`?

Comment: @Анатолий Михеенко, нет. `range(num2)` сформирует массив с элементами `0, 1, ... num2 - 1`, а `for cycle in` пробежит по массиву принимая последовательно все эти значения

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите строчку `num4 = num1/100*10` за пределы цикла:

```
#Вычисление 10% от введеного пользователем числа
num4 = num1/100*10
while num3 < num2:
    #Вычисление увиличения суммы с учетом процетов
    num4 = num4 + num1
```

Заодно можно упросить ее до `num4 = num1/10`.

Comment: Спасибо упрощение применил, но остановился на варианте                                     `num3 = 0
while num3 < num2:
    num4 += num1/10
    num3 = num3 + 1`